# Issue with Image transformation in android

Tags: android, transformation

I wrote a sample code for image transforming from top to bottom, by using transformation. Here, the image moving correctly, but the problem is, it's transformed under the controls. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Android Animation"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/xxl"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/xxl"
    android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
    />
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button android:text="AddToFavorites"
    android:id="@+id/AddToFavorites"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <Button android:text="AddToOrder"
    android:id="@+id/AddToOrder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menu">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If i click the button1, transformation of the image started, from top to bottom, but when it reaches the button , it moves the under of the button(i.e i won't visible at the place of the button, after crossing the button it's visible). My requirement is, i want to move the image over the controls(like, buttons, images, inner layouts..).

Thanks in advance...
Regards, 
Lokesh

Comment: How you do it depends on what layout you have.  Assuming this is a `RelativeLayout` (otherwise how would you do "layers"?) try putting `android:layout_below=...` on your image and specify to put it below the button.

Comment: [Here is my xml file](http://pastebin.com/gn4CzycN)

Comment: Add it to your question, please.

Comment: I didnt get clearly, I'm trying with android:layout_below=... , but there is no property like that... thank you for u r reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parent layout to RelativeLayout. And add some codes in the java to bring the views to front. You just use the function bringToFront() to bring the images in the top.

```
ImageView m=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
m.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Thanks Zacharias, It's working... thanks for u r response and logic.

Comment: @lokesh: You can do it in xml itself..In relativeLayout the last added content will be the top. That is in your xml file imageView1 will be at the top (if layout is relative).